# How do I alter the contents of a text file to be turned into a tupled dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a robot that prints the contents of a dictionary to a chat, when it detects a user asks for a Bible verse.

For instance if a user types "`Genesis 3:1`" I have a module that converts basic text into a tuple with 5 parts `["bookname",Startchapter,startverse,endchapter,endverse]`

And I have a text file that includes all verses in this exact form.

```
Genesis 1:1 Text.../n
Genesis 1:2 Text.../n
Genesis 1:3 text.../n
```

I'm trying to turn my text file into a dictionary, that can have its "text" called using the Tuple output of the scripture module.

However I cannot figure out how to make a dictionary with 3 keys and 1 text value to match up with the tuple output that will define what verses to pull.

How would I convert `"genesis 1:1 Text.."` and all other lines in the txt file, to a tupled dictionary that was formatted as `['Genesis',1,1,'text']`? Where the text will be called by the output of the Scripture module?

Where do I even start? Turning each line in the text file into a tuple?

I'm brand new to coding, so I don't really have an idea of whats going on.

Update

```
f = open("sacredGenesis.txt", 'r')
w = open('sacredGenesis2.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
    y = line.split(' ', 2)#as there are 2 spaces before and after 1:1
    for line in y:
        x = line.split(":", 1)#after splitting by space, splits up the 1:1
        strx = str(x)
        w.write(strx)
```

['Genesis']['1', '1']['Text./n']

Desired output ['Genesis',1,1,'text./n']

My code almost gives me what I want. It gives me 3 lists with 4 parts, instead of 1 list with 4 parts however. What am I going about wrong? Or is there a way to add every 3 lists together in python?

```
[x],[y],[z],[1],[2],[3]
```

How would I go about making a program to iterate through 90,000 lists to make it [x,y,z],[1,2,3]?

Comment: Almost any "Where do I start" question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: possibly related or helpful [most efficient way to convert text file contents into a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062691/most-efficient-way-to-convert-text-file-contents-into-a-dictionary-in-python/46062830), [How can I make each line in a data file a tuple in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051481/how-can-i-make-each-line-in-a-data-file-a-tuple-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Thank you @davedwards ! Hope people didn't think I was asking for them to do the work. Just didn't know the exact way to phrase it.

Comment: @BillBill no worries. If you still want to get a solution, as Prune mentioned, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54120700/edit) the question and just try to include an honest coding attempt and indicate where you get stuck or have problems -- then the question quality will be better, and then we can suggest solutions or answers. thanks.